# Find string that doesn't have prefix in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

To check that string has prefix have to use `STARTS WITH`, like:

```
MATCH (n:Person) WHERE n.name STARTS WITH 'Pet' RETURN
```

But how to check that string doesn't have prefix?

Tried next examples but no luck:

```
MATCH (n:Person) WHERE n.name NOT STARTS WITH 'Pet' RETURN
MATCH (n:Person) WHERE n.name STARTS NOT WITH 'Pet' RETURN
MATCH (n:Person) WHERE n.name NOT (STARTS WITH 'Pet') RETURN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
MATCH (n:Person) WHERE NOT n.name STARTS WITH 'Pet' RETURN n
```